# I'm having a hard time implementing my linked list class

Tags: java, linked-list

My goal is to make a linked list where each link is a char. I want it to take a string in as an argument, take the first letter and turn it into a char, and then pass the rest of the string onto the next link until the whole string is stored. This is what I have so far, although I'm not really sure which parts of it are correct or incorrect. I looked up a bunch of examples and this seemed to be the default setup.

```
public class linkedChar{

    char data;
    linkedChar head;
    linkedChar next;

    //This is the empty link constructor
    public linkedChar(){
        next = null;
    }
    //This is the constructor that takes a string
    public linkedChar(String input){
        if(input.length() > 0){
            data = input.charAt(0);
            next = new linkedChar(input.substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```

This code compiles but it's not working with my other manipulation methods. For example, my length method.

```
public int length(){
    int length = 0;
    linkedChar curr = head;
    while(curr != null){
        curr = curr.next;
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

When used, the length returned is always 0. I'm not sure which section of code has the error and I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructors, you're never initializing `head` to anything, so in your length method when you set `linkedChar curr = head;` you're setting `curr` to null  and thus `length` never gets incremented in your while loop.

Comment: Oh duh, that makes sense. Thanks! I was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor head=null, then in length method linkedChar curr = null; Hence length never gets incremented and remains at zero. Because the while loop does not satisfy the entry condition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to the `linkedChar head;` as Java compiler will zero out value(i.e set it as `null`) for you. Hence, your `length()` function will always stop at the first round.

A quick fix is to simply abandon the `linkedChar head` field and set `linkedChar curr` in your `length()` function to be `next`. This will fix your problem.

i.e. Make your code as following

```
class Linked{

  char data;
  Linked next;

  //This is the empty link constructor
  public Linked(){
    next = null;
  }
  public int length(){
    int length = 0;
    Linked curr = next;
    while(curr != null){
      curr = curr.next;
      length++;
    }
    return length;
  }

  //This is the constructor that takes a string
  public Linked(String input){
    if(input.length() > 0){
      data = input.charAt(0);
      next = new Linked(input.substring(1));
    }
  }
}

public class LinkedChar {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Linked l = new Linked("abcd");
    // Here it will print out 4
    System.out.println(l.length());
  }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.